# How can I discover that my device has rebooted, given that HONEYCOMB BOOT COMPLETED is no longer supported?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I am developing app in Android 4.0.3. I've read that the HONEYCOMB BOOT COMPLETED event is no longer supported, according to [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#api).

Given this, how can I discover that my device has rebooted?

CODE -

Java Class :-

```
public class MyStartupIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Logger.i("Device", "REBOOT");
        Logger.i("Device", "REBOOT");
        Logger.i("Device", "REBOOT");
        Logger.i("Device", "REBOOT");
        Logger.i("Device", "REBOOT");
    }
}
```

Manifest File :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="MyStartupIntentReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry , but perhaps you are wrong about the documentation , any way make sure that you are including `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` permission in your manifest . I use this broadcast in many apps and they works great.

Make sure you know aslo about this info  `BOOT_COMPLETE` is sent to applications before external storage is mounted. So if application is installed to external storage it won't receive `BOOT_COMPLETE` broadcast message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added code snippet of my code.. But its not working for me. Can you please kindly check and tell me where I am doing mistake.

Comment: is the package name in the manifest files is the same as the package which the your broadcast "MyStartupIntentReceiver" in ??

Answer (score 1):

> I am developing app in Android 4.0.3. I've read that the HONEYCOMB BOOT COMPLETED event is no longer supported, according to Google's documentation.

You misinterpreted the documentation. `BOOT_COMPLETED` is supported. However, it does require some component of your application to be run manually, before any registered `BroadcastReceiver` will work. Typically, this is done by starting an activity. Hence, if you just install an app and restart the device, you will not get control at boot time.

You can read more about this in [the "Launch controls on stopped applications" of the Android 3.1 release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols), as well as in [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html).