# Which Android class is in charge of sending the BOOT_COMPLETED intent?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, galaxy-tab, bootcompleted

I've been searching a lot regarding which Android class sends the BOOT_COMPLETED intent on KitKat 4.4.2 but I have not been able to find anything. Does anyone have a clue?

I have a Samsung SM-T230 device, maybe in this case is one of the Samsung applications the one that sends the intent?

Comment: According to the SDK document it is a protected intent only sent by the 'system'. You can handle it as long as you have the appropriate permission. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: @Karl Thanks for answering. Although I already knew that. What I need to know is which class sends it, in order for me to review it so I can understand the whole process. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171300/android-intent-boot-completed-is-never-launched-on-samsung-sm-t230-kitkat-4-4-2?noredirect=1#comment42833931_27171300) and you will understand my problem. This is a separete question though, with a different objective.